# Direct object or adverb?

Tags: grammar

Could somebody please tell me why the second adverb in the following sentence isn't a direct object? Thank you!

Luckily (ADV), no one (S) was hurt (V) in the accident (ADV)

Comment: Well, it didn’t get hurt, did it?

Comment: Where did the parse come from? And why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: The sentence came from an English teacher (so, I know it is correct) I was just wondering what I was missing.

Comment: You're looking at formulaic sentence structure rather than any sense of meaning; this is the major drawback of modern grammatical approaches. A direct object in the first instance refers to that which receives 'the action of the verb'. In 'Jack kicked Jill', the word 'Jill', getting kicked, is the DO corresponding to the 'patient', Jill herself. // 'Jill was hurt' is a passive sentence; we've missed out the 'by Jack' which would, as in the first sentence, refer to the 'agent', the naughty Jack. Jill, even though 'receiving the action' of the verb, is the subject now. There is no DO.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a direct object or an adverb, because of being followed by the preposition ,"in", and therefore makes the phrase a *prepositional phrase/an adverbial [of place].*

for instance

- in/to hospital
- in/to church

And so on....

As I was saying, I can't call it "an adverb" unless we are talking about words such as: *"nowhere, anywhere, everywhere, wherever, there, here, etc."* Those are referred to as ***"Adverbs Of Place"***.

Comment: Thank you for that!

Comment: In Luckily (ADV), no one (S) was hurt (V) in the arena (PP), the prepositional phrase is an adjunct (omitting it leaves a valid sentence with the same sense, albeit with less information) and could be labelled an 'adverbial of place' (defining the location where _no one was hurt_). OP's PP is similar, though the adverbial defines the event rather than the location involved.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Right. I included your opinion about "adverbial " in my answer, making it more complete. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence presented is in the passive voice with *no one*, which would be the object of *hurt* in the active voice, in subject position. As *hurt* is at most a monotransitive verb (allowing either one object or none), there couldn't possibly be an object of *hurt* in this construction.

Furthermore, by definition objects are noun phrases, and *in the accident* is a prepositional phrase headed by *in* with *the accident* being the object of *in*.